# How to toggle a panel's visibility

Tags: google-app-maker

I am trying to setup a hidden menu:

What is the onClick command for a button in "Panel_A", that would allow me to toggle the visibility of "Panel_B"?

Alternate scenario (if this simplifies things):

"Button A" in "Panel A" toggles visibility for "Panel B" as true.

"Button B" in "Panel B" toggles visibility for "Panel B" to hidden.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least two ways to do this.

1. Directly manipulating widgets visibility properties:

```js
// Button A click handler(toggles Panel B visibility)
var panelB = app.currentPage.descendants.PanelB;
panelB.visible = !panelB.visible;

// Button B click handler(hides Panel B)
app.currentPage.descendants.PanelB.visible = false;
```

2. Binding widgets visibility to page's custom property:

Let's assume that you have 'ShowB' Boolean Custom Property on your page and Panel's B visiblity property is bound to it:

```js
// Button A click handler(toggles Panel B visibility)
var props = app.currentPage.properties;
props.ShowB = !props.ShowB;

// Button B click handler(hides Panel B)
var props = app.currentPage.properties;
props.ShowB = false;
```

I personally prefer option 2, since it provides higher level of abstraction, makes code easier to read and refactor.

Comment: Was a little confused on option #2, so tried option #1. It works when I am doing a normal Page, but I failed to mention to I was trying to adjust a panel in a Page Fragment. When I try the same code with the Page Fragment I get: Cannot read property 'visible' of undefined at PageFragmentName.Form1.Form1Footer.Open.onClick:2:25.

Comment: I figured it out! Realized I needed "var menu = app.pageFragments.FragmentName.descendants.PanelB;". Thank you for your help!